# Java While Key Combination Not Pressed

Tags: java, key, combinations, command-prompt, keypress

i have a java command prompt that look for file changes in the directory and then edits the file.

I want to have a key combination like "Crtl + E" to exit the program.
The code should be like:

```
while(keyCom.NOTpressed){
**edit file**
}
```

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you meant checking key event from console and not from UI (Swing/Html etc).

Key event capturing from console is tougher than what it seems initially. It requires some native support.

Found this library here http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/ maybe you can take a look.

Comment: OMG that was very stupid of me. "Ctrl + C" already can end program just lime i want. BTW thank for your answer :3